# Issues with setIconImage()

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I am still quite a newbie when it comes to creating `JFrame` apps. I have decided to learn a bit more about it by creating a hobby of a project, all has been going pretty well, and I have learnt a lot, but now I'm trying to learn how to use `setIconImage()` for, ya know, the icon in the top left hand corner of the window (in Windows, not sure in which corner it is shown on Mac OSX and Linux). I have Googled far and wide, however could not really find anything that worked 100%, either it worked in Eclipse, or I got `NullPointerExceptions`. From what I understand is that when running the `.jar` file from your desktop, it would do a search for the icon image by starting at your PC's root directory, and not the `.jar`'s root directory. Anyone got some tips on this that might help? I have pasted my source code for the class that handles the `main` method for me below, the other classes deal with creating the `JFrame`, and in this case do the password generation (this is part of the tiny password generator app I made for my office)

Source Code:

```
    public class ShowWindowDemo()
    {
        private static final String ICON_PATH = "src\\images\\p_gen.png";

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            WindowDemo() gui = new WindowDemo();
            gui.setVisible(true);
            gui.setResizable(false);
            gui.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
                ShowWindowDemo.class.getResource(ICON_PATH)));
            gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            gui.setTitle("PassGen v1.0.6");
        }
    }
```

My folder structure for getting to the `.png` images is `src/images/`. Whenever I try to run my app in Eclipse using the above mentioned source code, it opens fine, but in my console I get a `NullPointerException`. I have run the app by using

```
    gui.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ICON_PATH));
```

and it works 100% fine.

Any assistance on this would be GREATLY appreciated, I am a bit stuck on this one it seems.

Comment: Why do you have the icon path with two `\\`   ?

Comment: Also, I would try to go to the icon and copy the full path (even with the main dirs, and see if it works)

Comment: I can use either \\ (can't use a single \ ), or /. I use \\ due to Windows using \. The thing with the icon is that it will only be displayed on the window itself once the Jar has been opened, not the desktop icon itself, additionally it won't be in the exact same folder on all my colleagues' PC's, thus if I were to use the actual full path from the C: drive, it might not work that well on most PC's.

Edit: I tried using /, made no difference in Eclipse, or the exported .jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `/images/p_gen.png` as ICON_PATH.
I am getting my icon image like this (i am using javafx, but it should be similar) :

```
primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/four85.png"));
```

Comment: You sir, deserve a cookie!

Answer (score 0):

Try create a folder named "Images" in your project and copy all the images in that folder.Then test this code:

```
gui.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResources("Images/image_name.png"),"An image"));
```

Hope that helps.